# Tripewire database and PTS for remote server

Tags: ssh

I am tired of the false positive caused by Tripwire scans, finding that /dev/pts/0 has been removed.

This connection is created for my SSH session when I remotely manage the system and update the Tripwire database. Beside using a shell script like the following:

```
$ sleep 30
$ nohup tripwire --init 2>&1 >nohup.out
```

... which rebuilds and destroys the database and loses history.

Does anyone have a solution for Tripwire to ignore my own /dev/pts on running --check --interactive  ?

Tim

Answer (score 0):

OP has had no activity in almost a year, but here is how to resolve that problem (provided I understood it correctly):

This is taken from [Justin Ellingwood](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-tripwire-to-detect-server-intrusions-on-an-ubuntu-vps): in your `twpol.txt` file in the category "Device and kernel information", you will find the section:

```
(
  rulename = "Devices & Kernel information",
  severity = $(SIG_HI),
)
{
        /dev            -> $(Device) ;
        /proc           -> $(Device) ;
}
```

You probably want to comment out `/proc` which gives you a lot of false positives, include instead a selection of the items you will find under `/proc/` on yr box, AND add

```
       /dev/pts         -> $(Device) ;
```

> *Tripwire will not check that location by default because it is told to
> check /dev, and /dev/pts is on a separate filesystem, which it will
> not enter unless specified. To get tripwire to check this as well, you
> can explicitly name it.*

HTH.